Shopify Storefront API how to pass key to variant fragment?
Rusty on my Graphql I'm using Shopify's Storefront API version 2024-10 I have a query of:
export const getProductQuery = /* GraphQL */ `
  query getProduct($handle: String!) {
    product(handle: $handle) {
      ...product
    }
  }
  ${productFragment}
`

in my Fragment I have:
import imageFragment from './image'
import seoFragment from './seo'

const productFragment = /* GraphQL */ `
  fragment product on Product {
    id
    handle
    availableForSale
    title
    description
    publishedAt
    tags
    descriptionHtml
    variants(first: 250) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          availableForSale
          selectedOptions {
            name
            value
          }
          price {
            amount
            currencyCode
          }
          metafield {
            key
            namespace
            type
          }
        }
      }
    }
    featuredImage {
      ...image
    }
    images(first: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...image
        }
      }
    }
    seo {
      ...seo
    }
    tags
    updatedAt
  }
  ${imageFragment}
  ${seoFragment}
`

export default productFragment

and per the documentation on metafield I'm required to pass the key identifier.
Research

Shopify Storefront API: Getting referenced variant with GraphQL
Search Product in Shopify Storefront API
Retrieving data from Shopify Storefront API
Shopify Storefront API. adding item to cart
How to fetch products from Shopify Storefront API

How can I get the metafield on the variant level from Shopify's Storefront API when I'm not sure what the required key should be?

You'll need just to pass "key" and "namespace" values to metafield field.
On metafield definition in your admin, you will find both namespace and key values. It'll be defined by {namespace}.{key}. e.g.: on you query, if value are "foo.bar":
variants(first: 250) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      title
      availableForSale
      selectedOptions {
        name
        value
      }
      price {
        amount
        currencyCode
      }
      metafield(namespace: "foo", key: "bar") {
        key
        namespace
        type
      }
      # you can rename the field if has more metafields to retrive, like
      myCustomField: metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "foo") {
        key
        namespace
        type
      }
    }
  }
}

